# How do I create a new question type that has the exact behaviour of an imagepicker question in Survey Creator but with custom rendering & properties?

Tags: surveyjs

I am trying to create a few extra question types to put in the toolbox for the SurveyJS Survey Creator.

I would like to create a carousel version of the imagepicker question that would be available from the toolbox in Survey Creator along side the existing imagepicker. I am not sure how to do this.
I am using jQuery and Knockout, I have no Angular or React experience (my server is in python).

How do I create a new question type and have it mimic an existing question type's default property grid/object properties and rendering so that I can have both versions available in the Survey Creator toolbox?

I tried following the "create specialized question types" country dropdown example, but that makes the Property Grid hide the questionJSON object properties, which I think means that the user in the Survey Creator cannot edit the choices. This lead to my carousel image picker not having image uploads, adding, or moving like the existing imagepicker question. Im not sure how to use the custom witdget to allow the user to upload the images, since I was just going to use it to do the animation in the afterRender. I noticed the enabledChoices property in the imagepicker api, but I have no idea how or where to use this property and I dont know what "ItemValue[] readonly" type is.

Im not sure if this is the best way to do this, but I made a country drop down with flag images that can be dragged and dropped from the toolbox in the Survey Creator using Survey.ComponentCollection.Instance.add to add the country question, and a custom widget to render the flags for all of the options/ selected option.

Also, I noticed that for https://surveyjs.io/form-library/examples/external-form-navigation-system/, the Vue example works as expected but both the jQuery and Knockout versions do not function correctly.

Comment: I am trying a custom widget using a class, where I extend Survey.QuestionImagePickerModel and just override getType(), in the init() {Survey.Serializer.addClass} and set isDefaultRender: true in hopes of it using the imagepicker renderer (what is its renderer called?). 
The property grid mostly matches the imagepicker property grid; however, nothing renders in the preview and only the action bar renders in the creator.

I am trying to follow/convert this example to using jquery:
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/crimson-https-3gy8cr?file=%2Fsrc%2FSurveyCreatorComponent.jsx%3A87%2C1-121%2C3